# Preserve shape on object on different subdivision levels in 3DSMax?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max, modeling

Is there a way or a feature or a modifier in 3DS Max like the "Turbo-smooth" modifier that would preserve the shape of an object on other subdivision levels after making changes to it on a high subdivision level? Here is what I mean -

- Level 4 -

[image]

[image]

- Level 2 -

[image]

[image]

Note - The polycount to be reduced like a "Turbosmooth" modifier in reverse (literally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Polygon Reduction.

**Optimize Modifier:**

Open the Modifier list and choose **Optimize**. Simply by changing the values on *Face Thresh* and *Edge Thresh* you are able to reduce the Polygon count. By using a Value of 10 and 20 on the Face and Edge Threshold respectively you will keep the most important details and remove the unnecessary polygons. But play around with the values to achieve your desired result.

*Note: I suggest you to convert the geometry to an **Editable Poly** before making the process.*

Comment: Thanks. I should've mentioned it in the post (Sorry. I'll make an update) - Can I reduce polygons like "Turbo-smooth" in reverse (literally)? In blender there's a "Multi-resolution" modifier that allow you to go on higher levels of subdivisions and then when you make a change, you can go back on previews levels and the shape will be maintained. Is that possible?

Comment: @Vladimir You are talking about LOD (levels of details), but that is another question :).

Comment: When I mentioned in the post the "..like the "Turbo-smooth" modifier", I meant to preserve the topology flow evenly in the way like the modifier does when using it. Anyway, sorry for the confusion. And is that possible?

Comment: @Vladimir, yes it is possible, the renderer will optimize the mesh based on the distance from the camera.